# Linked tables and Slicer in excel

Tags: excel, slicers

I can not create a slicer in excel that filters not only by the main table, too by a secondary table that should be linked with the first table with a field key that is the reference.

In other words, the main table is the students table with a unique ID that is reference. The secondary table are the classes that each student attends.

I want the Slicer to filter, to which classes each student attends and shows me the student table, only with the students that match the slicer selection of the secondary table. Is this possible?

Basically it would be like doing a select in Access.

Sorry I can't add an example file to this post and I add a [link to dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysiwzhijf7qzs1i/Libro1.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2013 or above, you can import both tables and add them to **data model**. then you can link those two tables in data model with a field key. After that you can use slicer on lookup table to filter both tables.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it isnt possible. I have the 2 tables in the same  Excel sheet. I dont have and neither cant import this tables. Excel only let me import external files, like access, xml, etc, but not from a table that is in the same Sheet.

Comment: Select table, go to insert pivot table, and be sure you select "add to data model". It works only on 2013/2016 excel. Do this to both tables. Then you can link them in design view.