# How to link a Table and a Pivot Table using more than one slicer in Excel?

Tags: pivot-table, slicers

I had the same problem about using slicers to link table and a Pivot Table. The ansewr provided by [[jeffreyweir]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2507160/jeffreyweir) was perfect! But in my case, I will need the solution for using 3 or more different slicers.

The initial solution can be found by following the link: [How to link a Table and a Pivot Table using Slicers in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617400/how-to-link-a-table-and-a-pivot-table-using-slicers-in-excel/49621404#49621404)

Many tks in advance and I hope I had follow the rules of this fantastic site in the right way! ;-)

Comment: You want multiple slicers because you want to filter on multilple columns/fields?

Comment: Exactly! For instance. User might want to filter one Region and then one (or more) managers responsible for sales in such place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've amended the code so that it only needs PivotTable slicers, and it uses those slicer setting to directly filter the Table. Note that you need to change the following lines in the code to match the names of your Table and PivotTable:

```
Const sPivot As String = "PivotTable1" '<= Change name as appropriate

Const sTable As String = "Table1" '<= Change name as appropriate
```

This code has to be pasted into the **sheet module** belonging to the worksheet where the Tables/PivotTables concerned are:

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim sLastUndoStackItem As String
Dim sc          As SlicerCache
Dim si          As SlicerItem
Dim vItems      As Variant
Dim i           As Long
Dim lo          As ListObject
Dim lc          As ListColumn
Dim sTest       As String

Const sPivot As String = "PivotTable1" '<= Change name as appropriate
Const sTable As String = "Table1" '<= Change name as appropriate

If Target.Name = sPivot Then
    On Error Resume Next 'in case the undo stack has been wiped or doesn't exist
    sLastUndoStackItem = Application.CommandBars(14).FindControl(ID:=128).List(1) 'Standard Commandbar, undo stack
    'The above line doesn't seem to work in my version of O365 so we'll use the English language backup
    If sLastUndoStackItem = "" Then sLastUndoStackItem = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If sLastUndoStackItem = "Filter" Or sLastUndoStackItem = "Slicer Operation" Then

        Set lo = Range(sTable).ListObject

        For Each sc In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
            On Error Resume Next
            sTest = sc.PivotTables(1).Name
            On Error GoTo 0
            If sTest = sPivot Then
                Set lc = lo.ListColumns(sc.SourceName)
                If sc.FilterCleared Then
                    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=lc.Index
                Else
                    ReDim vItems(1 To 1)
                    For Each si In sc.SlicerItems
                        If si.Selected Then
                            i = i + 1
                            ReDim Preserve vItems(1 To i)
                            vItems(i) = si.Name
                        End If
                    Next si

                    lo.Range.AutoFilter Field:=lc.Index, Criteria1:=vItems, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                    ReDim vItems(1 To 1)
                End If
            End If
        Next sc
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

And here it is in action:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Jeff sorry toaking me so long to give you a feedback. BUT YOU ARE A GENIOUS!!

Comment: Cool. Please mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: Many, many tks! Totally agree with your "Lord grant me the VBA skills to automate the things I cannot easily change; the knowledge to leverage fully off the inbuilt features that I can; and the wisdom to know the difference" :-D

Answer (score 0):

For people who have data table on a separate sheet from their pivot table, simply change

```
Set lo = Range(sTable).ListObject
```

to

```
Set lo = Sheets("table_sheet_name").Range(sTable).ListObject
```

and store the code in the pivot table sheet module.