# Linking table slicer with pivot table slicer in excel

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a data table named Tab1 and a pivot table named PivotTab1.
Each of the tables, both Tab1 and PivotTab1, have their own slicer.

How can I link the two slicers so that the data is filtered in a commutative way, i.e. if I go to the Tab1 slicer and select a field, it also affects the selection in the PivotTab1 pivot table.

I have tried to use the solution proposed in this question:

[How to link a Table and a Pivot Table using Slicers in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617400/how-to-link-a-table-and-a-pivot-table-using-slicers-in-excel)

also from here:

[How to link a Table and a Pivot Table using Slicers in non-English Excel versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68031058/how-to-link-a-table-and-a-pivot-table-using-slicers-in-non-english-excel-version)

I have even downloaded the example file used in the first and second solution, but it does not work; apparently in current versions of office the code provided works, since the answer was given more than 4 years ago and the second one more than 2 years ago.

I would greatly appreciate your answers.
thank you.

P.S. I have Microsoft 365 professional, each table is on separate sheets in the same workbook, and I use as main language English as well as Spanish.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by 'does not work' - did you get an error (if so, what error number, what error text, on what line) or did it not give you the result you had hoped for (in which case describe what did happen). Also, you say "apparently in current versions of office the code provided works" but you are using MS 365 which is current (so long as you are applying MS updates to your device).